# Sass 3.3.0 'NoMethodError' -error when using '--watch'

Tags: sass

Just installed the brand new stable Sass 3.3.0 (Maptastic Maple) on both Mac and Windows. When using a `-f --update sass:css` it's working fine. But when using `--watch` I'm getting a `NoMethodError` -error.

Without --trace:

```
C:\RemoteProjects\sass-sourcemaps>sass --style expanded --sourcemap --watch sass:css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
NoMethodError:
```

With --trace

```
C:\RemoteProjects\sass-sourcemaps>sass --style expanded --watch ./:../css --trace
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:327:in `listen_to': undefined method `thread' for #<Listen::Listener:0x00000003c95d58> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:294:in `watch'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/lib/sass/plugin.rb:108:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/lib/sass/exec.rb:509:in `watch_or_update'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/lib/sass/exec.rb:346:in `process_result'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/lib/sass/exec.rb:43:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/lib/sass/exec.rb:22:in `parse!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.0/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/sass:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
```

Does anybody have any idea? We really need the `--watch` feature for local development.

Comment: Same here :( Any ideas?

Comment: As a temporary workaround I've reverted to an old version of SaSS, execute "sudo gem uninstall sass" and then "sudo gem install sass -v 3.2.15". Meanwhile you may want to subscribe to https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1151

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Jose Gonzalez for the linked https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1151 page. As described on that page the fix is to remove the `listen` v2.7.0 gem and revert back to `listen` v2.4.1 gem.

On Mac prefix the commands below with `sudo`

#### So just update to Sass 3.3.0:

`gem update sass`

#### Check if you have a newer version of the `listen` gem, run:

`gem list`

#### If you have `listen` v2.7.0 AND v2.4.1, then you need to uninstall the newer `listens` gem. Then it will use v2.4.1.

`gem uninstall listen --version '2.7.0'`

This worked for me. The Sass 3.3.0 `--watch` command is now working properly.

Comment: The Sass team seems to have fixed the issue in Sass 3.3.1. See https://github.com/nex3/sass/commits/stable. So the above is is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has been solved in Sass v3.3.1 according to the bug report I linked to in my previous comment:

[Trouble with 3.3 and --watch #1151](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1151)